# FATAL EXCEPTION on running a thread on Android App

Tags: java, android

```
03-11 08:50:46.911 8208-8233/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: MX Notifier
                                             Process: com.example.gec1ply.situationalautonomy, PID: 8208
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                 at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:119)
                                                 at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:200)
                                                 at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:1086)
                                                 at com.bosch.SituationalAutonomy.MainActivity.onCanMessageTimedOut(MainActivity.java:444)
                                                 at com.bosch.Platform.CAN.IO.OBDLink.OBDLinkMXNotifier.run(OBDLinkMXNotifier.java:39)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The goal of this question is to understand the error, because I have NO IDEA where to begin looking. Especially since the first callback is from Thread.run()

I am successfully capable of running this app on an emulator without throwing any exceptions, which leads me to believe that the program might be having issues connecting with BlueTooth, but the timing of the error during the runtime doesn't lead me to believe that is the case.

If you need any code examples, please comment and let me know. Thank you :)

Comment: Start by looking at MainActivity line 444. Your issue is that you need to jump onto the main thread before showing a dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to show an `AlertDialog` from a thread that is not the main thread. Doing so results in this error. When you get your `onCanMessageTimedOut`, you should send a message to the main thread in order to show your `AlertDialog`. If you have a reference to an `Activity`, you can use `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` for example

Answer (score 0):

Usually in various platforms like `Android`, the UI is rendered on the `main thread.` It usually has a `Queue` in which various `Requests` are enqueued. `Main thread` does continuous polling of this `Queue`, consumes the request and process the same on the UI. In case any other thread tries to modify the state of the UI elements then exception is thrown.

So to have any modifications done using any thread other than the main Ui thread, pass the message to the main UI thread. In frameworks Like Android there is some or the other mechanism provided for communication with main thread from other threads. I suggest you to please ready about Handler.java for Android. You should also study about AsyncTask.

Hope this helps...